# What is stdole2.tlb

Tags: com, atl, midl

stdole32.tlb contains all base type definitions, and every lib must import it, if we use MIDL. But when I created ATL DLL project, lib file looks like that

```
import "oaidl.idl";
import "ocidl.idl";

[
    uuid(4CA3ADAD-AE53-4D80-AF26-176BAF8223B1),
    version(1.0),
]
library FirstATLLib
{
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");
};
```

I can't google what is in stdole2.tlb? Does it contain stdole32.tlb? And what else? Can someone helps me to find out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Windows SDK `COM/OLE Object Viewer` to open the type library and see what is there inside:

[image]

It defines certain interfaces and type you can use in your type library, since you make them available through referencing `stdole2.tlb`.

Comment: it says "Bad extension for file" when I try to open stdole2.tlb

Comment: You might be doing something wrong, but don't worry - I did open it and I attached a screenshot for you.

Comment: yes, I used the wrong menu item. Weird, when I try to open stdole32.tlb it still opens stdole2.tlb

Answer (score 1):

`stdole2.tlb` is a newer version of `stdole32.tlb`. This is evident from the IDL exported using OleView:

From **stdole2.tlb**:

```
// typelib filename: stdole2.tlb

[
  uuid(00020430-0000-0000-C000-000000000046),
  version(2.0),
  helpstring("OLE Automation")
]
library stdole
{
...
```

From **stdole32.tlb**:

```
// typelib filename: stdole32.tlb

[
  uuid(00020430-0000-0000-C000-000000000046),
  version(1.0),
  helpstring("OLE Automation")
]
library stdole
{
...
```

This is confirmed by observing that they both have the same `uuid` but that `stdole2` has a later `version` attribute.

Furthermore if you compare the IDL for both of them you can see specifically how the newer one differs from the first. Mainly it adds some attributes to a few interfaces, and also adds a bunch of new typedefs, interfaces, etc. (Too long to add here and not really needed to answer the question).

Curiously unlike a DLL there are no file attributes (Details tab of the Properties view in Windows Explorer) with version or other info.